# How can I nest a rails resource inside another when creating a post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I am building a book repository in rails and I need to be able to add an author inside a book create form that passes the author post into the list of authors once the book has been added. In the same book creation resource I have already created the has_many: authors in the book.rb file and in the author.rb file I have created the belongs_to: author and that works fine I can select the books that author might have created with the following setup:

**book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :jacket_cover, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :jacket_cover, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    validates :jacket_cover, :title, :synopsis, :body, presence: true

    belongs_to :author

    scope :available, ->{ where(available: true) }
    scope :unavailable, ->{ where(available: [nil, false]) }

end
```

**author.rb**

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
end
```

**books_controller.rb**

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end


  def show
  end

  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  # GET /books/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update(book_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :synopsis, :body, :jacket_cover)
    end
end
```

**authors_controller.rb**

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_author, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @authors = Author.all
  end
  def show

  end
  def new
    @author = Author.new
  end

  # GET /authors/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  def create
    @author = Author.new(author_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.save
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @author }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.update(author_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @author.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to authors_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_author
      @author = Author.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def author_params
      params.require(:author).permit(:name, :biography, :books_ids => [] )
    end
end
```

This allows me to create the books and the authors which is fine but I am now looking to nest the author create into my book create too.

**form for book create**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@book, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.file_field :jacket_cover %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :synopsis %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**form for author create**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@author) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.association :books, 
                     as: :check_boxes, 
                     value_method: :id,
                     label: 'Books' %>
    <%= f.input :biography %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to nest another resource into an already created resource so adding an author create inside a book create page?

Comment: check [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat verbose, but I'll detail what you need to know

--

**Nested Objects**

> **Is it possible to nest another resource into an already created resource so adding an author create inside a book create page?**

Rails is built on top of Ruby (an [object orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language). This means Rails is object orientated too, and so if you wanted to create an *author* at the same time as creating a book (this is only applicable for `create`), you'll want to use the [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) directive for your model:

```
#app/models/book.rb
Class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :author
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
end

#app/controllers/books_controller.rb
Class BooksController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @book = Book.new
      @book.build_author #-> this will be authors.build if multiple
   end

   def create
      @book = Book.new(book_params)
      @book.save
   end

   private

   def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :synopsis, :body, author_attributes: [:biography])
   end
end
```

This will allow you to create the following (using `form_for` for simplicity sake):

```
#app/views/books/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
   <%= f.text_field :synopsis %>
   <%= f.text_field :body %>

   <%= f.fields_for :author do |a| %>
      <%= a.text_field :biography %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will create the book record & associated author record, too

Comment: will be able to add an author inside the book create page as well as create the book here?

Comment: When you say "add an author", what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,you need **[accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)** and **[simple_fields_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)** helper provided for the `simple_form_for`(as you are using `simple_form_for`)

**Step #1**

In your `Book` model,you should add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :author`

**Step #2**

Modifying your new method of books_controller.rb

As you have `belongs_to :author` in your `Book` model,your `new` method of your `BooksController` would be

```
def new
@book = Book.new
@book.build_author #This is very important
end
```

**Step #3**

Your `book_params` method should be modified to

```
def book_params
params.require(:book).permit(:title, :synopsis, :body, :jacket_cover,author_attributes: [:name,:biography,..,..])
end
```

**Step #4**

Finally,your `form` for `book create` would be something like this

```
<%= simple_form_for(@book, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.file_field :jacket_cover %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :synopsis %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
  </div>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :author do |a| %>

  ... author fields...
  ....................
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so to clarify Pavan, I will be able to add an author inside the book create page as well as create the book here?

Comment: You should maybe clarify that the `simple_fields_for` comes from the `simple_form` gem. It is not really required, the OP could as well use `form_for` and `fields_for` but I think it is a good idea to use `simple_form` anyway :)

Comment: @nathanvda I have updated my answer to make it clear :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to nest another resource into an already created resource so adding an author create inside a book create page?

Yes.

You probably want a longer answer than that though.

You need to get [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

In Book model:

```
 has_one :author, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors
```

In BooksController `:new` add line

```
 @book = Author.new
 @book.build_author
```

And in form for `@book`:

```
<%= form_for(@book, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="inputs">
#book fields
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :author do |author| %>
#author fields
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And don't forget to modify book_params method as shown in answer by Rich Peck.

Comment: Hi andrey, just a quick query about this. When I add a new book will this allow me to create the author profile on the new book page?

Comment: in order to do so you'll need to set up the models vice versa (so that author info will be within book form). Meaning using @book.build_author in :new action in books_controller and so on (i'll modify the answer)